# symfony1.4 propel1.5 audit log

Tags: logging, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, audit

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with the Propel 1.5 plugin.

I need to create an audit log that shows reads/writes to the database - with the user who's logged in.

I would like to turn on full query logging to a separate file. If I use a custom logger class, I could insert the username before logging.

How can I do this in symfony?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following behavior: https://github.com/Carpe-Hora/AuditableBehavior.
It has been written by a Propel core team member :)